# How to go back to previous class?

Tags: android, android-button

I created in my program back Button in my ActionListener I raised the activity that I want to return to it, but the problem that I when I pressed it restarts the activity. But I want him to have the same behavior as the button back of Android. now i use

```
final Button boutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
                boutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(ResultActivity.this,
                                AppList.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);

                    }
                }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `getActivity().onBackPressed()` if your code is in `Fragment` or `onBackPressed()` if your code is in `Activity`. Make sure that you do not override `onBackPressed()`. This solution is coherent. Override `onBackPressed()` will change behaviour of onClick method on your button.

```
final Button boutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
            boutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `finish()` the current activity. It will go back to the previous activity

"**the problem that I when I pressed it restarts the activity**" which means, you finished() the previous activity.

So, don't use `finish()` in the previous activity, just `finish()` the current activity only

In your current activity,

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(ResultActivity.this,
    yourpreviousactivity.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
    finish();
```

Comment: when, i finish() this activity, it will be back to the main Activity

Comment: don't use finish() in the previous activity. see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Just call `finish()` in your `onClick` method

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no use of firing `intent`

just call `finish()` that will do the trick for you.

```
See this, hope it will work


final Button boutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
            boutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   finish();

                }
            });
```